# boost asio 1.66 examples won't build - async_connect() which takes a single iterator fails to link on VS2010

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010, boost-asio

When I try to compile the sample ssl client program taken from the asio website, using multithreaded debug, multibyte characterset configuration I get a linker error:

> asioclient2010.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl boost::asio::async_connect,class boost::_bi::bind_t,class boost::_bi::list2,struct boost::arg<1> > > >(class boost::asio::basic_socket &,class boost::asio::ip::basic_resolver_iterator,class boost::_bi::bind_t,class boost::_bi::list2,struct boost::arg<1> > > const &,void *)" (??$async_connect@Vtcp@ip@asio@boost@@V?$basic_resolver_iterator@Vtcp@ip@asio@boost@@@234@V?$bind_t@XV?$mf1@XVclient@@ABVerror_code@system@boost@@@_mfi@boost@@V?$list2@V?$value@PAVclient@@@_bi@boost@@U?$arg@$00@3@@_bi@3@@_bi@4@@asio@boost@@YAXAAV?$basic_socket@Vtcp@ip@asio@boost@@@01@V?$basic_resolver_iterator@Vtcp@ip@asio@boost@@@ip@01@ABV?$bind_t@XV?$mf1@XVclient@@ABVerror_code@system@boost@@@_mfi@boost@@V?$list2@V?$value@PAVclient@@@_bi@boost@@U?$arg@$00@3@@_bi@3@@_bi@1@PAX@Z) referenced in function "public: __thiscall client::client(class boost::asio::io_context &,class boost::asio::ssl::context &,class boost::asio::ip::basic_resolver_iterator)" (??0client@@QAE@AAVio_context@asio@boost@@AAVcontext@ssl@23@V?$basic_resolver_iterator@Vtcp@ip@asio@boost@@@ip@23@@Z)

If I build it as a VS2017 project it links fine. I'm guessing its a problem with the version of boost?

What is the latest version of boost that is compatible with VS2010?

http://think-async.com/Asio/boost_asio_1_10_6/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp03/ssl/client.cpp

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: this is not a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the version of async_connect which takes a single iterator fails to link on VS2010.

```
boost::asio::async_connect(socket_.lowest_layer(), 
     endpoint_iterator,
     boost::bind(&client::handle_connect, 
                 this,
                 boost::asio::placeholders::error));
```

According to the documentation:

> This overload assumes that a default constructed object of type
>   Iterator represents the end of the sequence. This is a valid
>   assumption for iterator types such as
>   boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator.

Calling the second overload of async_connect and explicitly passing in an end iterator solves the issue:

```
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator dummy_end_iterator;
    boost::asio::async_connect(socket_.lowest_layer(),
        endpoint_iterator, dummy_end_iterator,
        boost::bind(&client::handle_connect, 
                    this,
                    boost::asio::placeholders::error));
```

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/async_connect.html

Answer (score 1):

`What is the latest version of boost that is compatible with VS2010?`

[The latest version of boost (1.66.0) is compatible.](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/log/doc/html/log/installation.html)

---

Aside from that you will have to specify at least the library directory of your boost version in your `Linker -> Additional Library Directories` settings.

For SSL you will ALSO have to specify the library path and the corresponding library files in your linker / command line. The current version of boost is compatible with the newer SSL versions (1.1.0#) too so this is not a problem either.

You can check the dependencies inside the `DEPENDENCY_VERSIONS.txt` when downloading the binaries.

> Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 - msvc-10.0 - Service Pack 1

SSL Additional Library Directories and command-line for the linker are here as a sample. These are depending on your installation & version - here I am using OpenSSL 1.1.0f 64-bit.

SSL Additional Library Directories:

> C:\OpenSSL-Win64\lib

Command-line:

> "libssl.lib" "libcrypto.lib"

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am using openssl 1.1.0f 32 bit too.

Comment: When I build it as a VS2017 project it works fine.

The server code from the asio examples also works fine built under VS2010.

http://think-async.com/Asio/boost_asio_1_10_6/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp03/ssl/server.cpp

It seems to have a problem with this line of code failing to link:

  boost::asio::async_connect(socket_.lowest_layer(),
   endpoint_iterator, 
   boost::bind(&client::handle_connect, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error));